# solve the ODE: $y'=\frac{y\cos x}{1+2y^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a simple way without computers to solve for $y$ for this ODE?

$$y'=\frac{y\cos x}{1+2y^2}$$

Comment: Yes: the equation is separable.

Comment: I think OP is asking to solve for $y$ in the answer $\log y+\frac{1}{4} y^2 = \sin x+C$.

Comment: In that case, there doesn't seem to be a solution in terms of the elementary functions. Wolfram gives something involving the Lambert W function, but I think that's the best you can do for a transcendental equation like this.

Comment: addendum: But at the very least, we have an implicit form for the solution $y(x)$, which isn't bad. In an undergrad ODE course I think this answer would be acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

First, we note that the ODE is separable and find

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y\cos x}{1+2y^2} \implies \int \cos (x) \,dx=\int \frac{1+2y^2}{y}\,dy \tag 1$$

Next, carrying out the integrals in $(1)$ reveals

$$\log(y)+y^2=sin(x)+C \implies ye^{y^2}=C'e^{\sin(x)} \tag 2$$

Squaring $(2)$ and multiplying by $2$ yields

$$2y^2e^{2y^2}=C''e^{2\sin(x)}\implies \bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{y=\pm \sqrt{\frac{W\left(C''e^{2\sin(x)}\right)}{2}}}$$

where $W(z)$ is the [Lambert W Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and $C''>0$ is an integration constant